# How Can A Non-Config File Be Loaded through a JSP Running in Tomcat 8.0

Tags: java, eclipse, jsp, tomcat, servlets

In Eclipse Luna I have a *Dynamic Web Project* (with default build settings) on *Apache Tomcat 8.0*.  In the project, I have a JSP `loader.jsp` that calls a method in a Java class `FileLoader` that returns a `String` value for the location of a non-config txt file (lets call it *key.txt*).

My issue is that I am getting a null value for the file location when `FileLoader` tries to get `key.txt` and return its location.

Here is an idea of what I've tried and failed with:

In `FileLoader` constructor I pass it `String "key.txt"` as a value and it has a method called get `getKeyPath()` that returns the file path.  I use the following in `getKeyPath()` to get the file path:

```
String path = this.getClass().getClassLoader().getResource("key.txt").getFile();
```

The path variable is returned to the calling object.  Here is how I call `getKeyPath()` in `loader.jsp`:

```
String keyPath = new FileLoader("key.txt").getKeyPath();
```

My issue is that a `NullPointerException` is thrown in `FileLoader` when `getKeyPath()` tries to set the path value.  I am lost because this happens no matter where I put the physical "key.txt" in my project directory or at file paths that should be recognized by my project.  In my project I have tried the above code with key.txt at the following paths (assume the root folder for my project in Eclipse is called PRO):

> PRO/build/classes 
>   PRO/build 
>   PRO/WebContent/WEB-INF/lib 
>   PRO/WebContent(where loader.jsp is located) 
>   PRO/Java Resources/src (Tomcat Install)
>   Dir>/lib /bin

I got the same `NullPointerException` for all attempts.  Once I resorted to the Tomcat directories I realized I needed help.

Is there something else I need to do so "key.txt" can be loaded in the way I want?  Am I doing this completely wrong?  I can post screenshots if that would make answering this easier.

As an aside, due to application requirements, I'd prefer that `loader.jsp` not load *key.txt* directly.  Of course, I'll have to do that if what I'm trying is not possible.

Please note that I am trying to do this in an Eclipse Dynamic Web Project so there is no "bin" folder like a standard Java project.  Finally, I'd prefer not to make any build config changes in Eclipse but of course I will if I have to.

Comment: In effort to clarify the paths I attempted saving the txt file to due to all paths being presented on one line above...1) PRO/build/classes, 2) PRO/build, 3) PRO/WebContent/WEB-INF/lib, 4) PRO/WebContent, 5) PRO/Java Resources/src, 6)  TomcatInstallDir/lib, 7) TomcatInstallDir/bin

Comment: Try FileLoader FileLoader fileLoader = new FileLoader("key.txt");
  String keyPath = fileLoader.getKeyPath(); and put a debug point to see it is getting initialized. Can you post stacktrace and code inside `FileLoader `

Comment: If there was an issue with file loading you will be getting a different exception unless you code is swallowing that.

Comment: Thanks for the advice.  Separating the class initialization from the method call as recommended above fixed my problem.  The txt file was read in from the ProjectDir/WebContent/WEB-INF/lib folder.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Separate out the initialization and calling of the method into two separate lines.

Problem is not that file is not loaded but rather that at the time `.getKeyPath();` is called object initisation is not done and that the reason for `NullPointer`

So change to this :

```
FileLoader FileLoader fileLoader = new FileLoader("key.txt"); 
String keyPath = fileLoader.getKeyPath();
```